# SQL Trigger for reverting an update change on a table only when another column has specific values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger for what was done as a rather simple job before, so that it fires immediately after change. This was the code for the job.

```
UPDATE       GrdFelde
SET                GrdInhalt = 0
WHERE        (GrdNummer LIKE 'BEST[A-Z][A-Z]%2') AND (GrdInhalt <> 0)
```

This is what I have so far.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[GrdFelde_UTrig_Custom] ON [dbo].[GrdFelde] FOR UPDATE AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF UPDATE(GrdInhalt)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE       GrdFelde
        SET                GrdInhalt = 0
        WHERE        (GrdNummer LIKE 'BEST[A-Z][A-Z]%2') AND (GrdInhalt <> 0)
    END
```

I am new to triggers and not sure if this works. My problem here is, this is a table that stores all changes to a user interface, so it updates quite often, and I don't want to cause performance problems. Is it possible that the trigger only fires when the WHERE criteria are met? And if yes, where would I put this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger will be fired whenever an update statement is executed on the table. This can not be controlled (except disabling the trigger entirely).
You can, however, write it for better performance.

1. The [`UPDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function will return `1` even if the update/insert statement fails, so you probably don't want to use that as an indicator.
2. You have no reference to the `inserted` or to the `deleted` tables in your trigger, meaning it might effect records not included in the original update statement that triggers it.

I would probably write that trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[GrdFelde_UTrig_Custom] ON [dbo].[GrdFelde] 
FOR UPDATE AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE t
    SET GrdInhalt = 0
    FROM GrdFelde t
    JOIN INSERTED i ON t.<PKColumn(s)> = i.<PKColumn(s)>
    JOIN DELETED d  ON t.<PKColumn(s)> = d.<PKColumn(s)>
    WHERE t.GrdNummer LIKE 'BEST[A-Z][A-Z]%2'
    AND t.GrdInhalt <> 0
    AND ISNULL(CAST(i.GrdInhalt AS INT), -1) <> ISNULL(CAST(d.GrdInhalt AS INT), -1)

GO
```

**Please note**:

1. By joining the `inserted` and `deleted` tables, I'm ensuring the trigger only changes the rows effected by the statement that fired it.
2. Change `<PKColumn(s)>` to the column(s) that makes up the primary key of the table.
3. I'm casting to `int` and specifing `-1` for null values to handle the case of change from null to a value or from a value to null. If your column is already an int, then the cast is redundant. If `-1` is a valid value, you might want to consider casting to `varchar(11)` and replace `null` with an empty string.

Comment: That worked a charm. Now the app always starts with nothing selected, that saves a ton of time. Thank you very much.